# Idiomatic way to pass different types of a "base" struct over RPC?

Tags: go

I'm setting up a Client that makes an RPC call `GetTask` to a Server, which conceptually responds with either a `MapTask` or a `ReduceTask` but in fact is just a single base struct type. Both a `MapTask` and a `ReduceTask` have a single field `filename`, but need to be differentiated by the Client for downstream processing. One way I thought of defining this struct in Go was:

```
type Task struct {
  filename string
  taskType string
}
```

Where `taskType` would be either `"map"` or `"reduce"`. Then there could be some helper functions on this struct type the Client could use to figure out which type of `Task` it received:

```
func (t *Task) isMapTask() bool {
  t.taskType == "map"
}

func (t *Task) isReduceTask() bool {
  t.taskType == "reduce"
}
```

This would work reasonably well, and hides complexity / implementation details within the struct type. One problem I see is that there is no constraint on what value `taskType` can have -- so the Client could receive a `Task` that is neither of type Map or Reduce. Another concern I have is I'm not sure if there are some pitfalls with this structure I'm not thinking of.

My question is whether the above structure is reasonable and/or idiomatic for Go?

As a small aside, I'm coming from an OO background in Ruby and I could imagine the following structure in Ruby pseudo-code:

```
class BaseTask

class MapTask < BaseTask

class ReduceTask < BaseTask
```

And this of course doesn't map nicely to Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options you can implement are:

1. What you already did. It is simple and readable. If the client receives a taskType that is not a supported type, it can simply return an error
2. Use two structs in the client, MapTask and ReduceTask, optionally with a common base. You can use two separate wire messages, or one message with a message type in it. The RPC client handler can translate the received message to one of the structs based on the message type.

Comment: Option 2 is very interesting, I didn't think of approaching it that way. This gives me some food for thought, thanks.